# Grouping in the "Processes" tab of Task Manager

Tags: vb.net, windows-8

How do I have my application's process to show like "Adobe Acrobat Update Service" and other processes which also don't appear on Apps group, but on Background processes group?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different groups that show up in the Processes tab of Task Manager:

- Apps - any processes that are showing UI (have a top-level window)
- Background Processes - any non-UI, non-Windows processes
- Windows Processes - any non-UI, Windows processes

Processes can move between groups while they are running.  This can be demonstrated pretty easily using Windows Explorer.  Windows Explorer will show up in either the Apps or Windows Processes group depending upon whether it is showing any UI (for example, the Run dialog or a folder).

Comment: And what should I do in order to make my Windows Form Application to run as a Background process?

Comment: In order for a process to be grouped as a Background Process, it cannot show UI.  Specifically, a Windows Form Application can be written so that it does not show any Forms (no UI).

Comment: I understand that. The thing is, my Form doesn't have anything on it, besides two timers, yet, it does show as App. What Kind of command or specific configuration should I make in order to my application's process show as Background process? That's what I'm asking.