# How window task manager group processes under an application?

Tags: process, window, taskmanager

As titled, I am wondering how window task manager group processes into 1 application name. Please see below picture for what I want to do.

[image: window task manager]

I have checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219028/grouping-in-the-processes-tab-of-task-manager). Therefore, I have 2 questions.

1. How to have an application process to house rest of the processes (including background process) in the task manager such that I can monitor the performance of the application at all
2. How to rename that root application, and the icon since my application is spawning some python processes at background etc. I would like to name them as "company product" instead of "python" in the task manager.

Any guidelines will be appreciated.

Some more background:

- In our application, we spawn many processes (python, postgres, redis etc)
- Currently, we bundle the entire application as window application via inno setup
- The actual start up process:

  - Launch a python script (`__main__.py`)
  - Create the necessary UI components
  - Create background processes like redis, postgres etc

Comment: This is the answer I came across: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950088.

The value of `InheritedFromUniqueProcessId` is probably what the Task Manager uses to group the processes. This may be able to get you started.